# Restructure connected google drives

Tags: python, database, google-drive-api, cloud, data-transfer

I want to reorganize a series of linked google drives. Currently, each drive contains files corresponding to a letter (A-Z), and I want to reorganize them, so the files are organized by year instead. There is a massive amount of data in each drive, so it would take a lot of time to share and then copy files from one to another, and there are also many different file types. I've looked at some cloud transfer solutions, but if anyone knows if this is feasible with the drive API please let me know. I've looked at the documentation, but I'm not sure how to apply it to a transfer this large.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Drive API, specifically the [files listing](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) via the [Google Python library](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) to list the files by page and store those in a file or database. Then, sort them accordingly with help of Python or the database.

To copy files between accounts, try [rclone](https://rclone.org/drive/). It supports the server-side copy feature (`--drive-server-side-across-configs`) which means the file doesn't have to be downloaded and uploaded locally and instead is copied on the Google drive side. This should be significantly faster.